# Crystal tolerances and what that means for timer interrupts

Tags: clock, timer, interrupts, crystal, rtc

I'm developing a system that needs to periodically wake up and perform a process. We're currently targeting for an hourly wake up (give or take, this spec is very loose).

The key here is the unit cost and I really hope to avoid a real time clock on board. We're even trying to avoid an external crystal, if possible.

I expect some amount of drift if we decide to rely on the MCU's internal clock for timing. However, is there any way to minimize this drift? Is it common practice to calibrate the interrupt timer to reduce drift at the factory?

Are there any other options I'm not considering?

Comment: Which MCU would this be? Because the answer depends on it.

Comment: If your spec is loose then why are you trying to  minimize it? Just check to see if it is acceptable.

Comment: Watch crystals (32768Hz) are cheap. The rest of the required hardware is probably already part of your MCU.

Comment: Internal oscillators can be a few percent off from their nominal frequencies. All depends on the MCU you use, how loose your spec is, and if using an external crystal is acceptable. Rough ballpark guestimate: an error of a few minutes per hour when using an MCU's internal oscillator. YMMV. There usually are calibration registers, but the achievable precision is still very limited.

Comment: Which MCU are you using, and what tolerance do you have in the wake-up timing (milliseconds, seconds, minutes)?

Comment: Here's the MCU datasheet: 

http://www.tenx.com.tw/Files/Doc/1686/DS-TM56F8225_EV093.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCU of your choice has an internal oscillator called FIRC, and it is likely to be calibrated at factory and datasheet says it has a tolerance of +/- 2%, over the whole temperature range and whole supply voltage range.

Therefore, 2% of an hour is 72 seconds, or 1 minute and 12 seconds.

So without further tricks, the hourly event is guaranteed to happen within +/- 72 seconds from the previous.

If temperature and/or supply voltage are constant, the accuracy will be even better.

The FIRC frequency can be adjusted by user, but it is loaded with factory calibration value on reset. The factory calibration conditions are temperature at 25 degrees C and supply voltage of 4.0V which guarantee +/- 0.5% accuracy, so if you use it in other conditions that are relatively constant, you can calibrate it yourself.

Other tricks to improve accuracy is to fine tune the calibration value based on supply voltage and temperature, but measuring these may also need some external components.

Unfortunately, the MCU has no pins to connect an external crystal directly, so a cheap 2 cent 32768 Hz watch crystal is not an option. It only has a counter input pin to count pulses from an external square wave clock source, so at least a clock oscillator with 32768 Hz square wave output can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Some chips have an internal RC oscillator that is "calibrated" at the factory, and you won't likely do much better without herculean efforts such as individual characterization in a temperature chamber. And even so it may not be all that stable. The target there for the chip suppliers is things like reliable serial communications where +/-1% is more than good enough. A real time clock is specified more likely in tens of ppm (roughly three orders of magnitude more accurate) to be acceptable. +/-20ppm represents 1.7 seconds gained or lost per day, and that's a typical 32kHz crystal spec. Higher frequency crystals can be a bit looser.

So, unless you have an external reference you can talk to (ntp or whatever) you should seriously consider the 2-cent crystal. You can trim the crystal frequency in with a small adjustable capacitor or adjust it digitally to get better than the 20ppm spec, especially if the temperature is relatively stable. There are other options such as resonators but they're not much (maybe 10:1) better than the calibrated RC oscillators, which still leaves 100:1 deficit.

Comment: Is a crystal actually 2 cents? Or is it just a figure of speech meaning it's cheap?

Comment: LCSC has Suzhou Liming Electronic 32.768kHz +/-10ppm crystals for $25 for 1,000. Lower price in high quantity, and lower again if you don't go through distribution. Lower prices available in small quantity but the quality might not be top drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying which MCU you are using, the internal oscillators inside of an MCU are typically somewhere around +/- 2~5% depending on which MCU and the operating temperature range.

The cheapest solution is probably going to be to add a 32KHz external oscillator and run the MCU timer blocks from that clock source.  You can get a clock source with uncalibrated accuracy < 50ppm for under 50 cents.  Its hard to beat that.

The other strategy is factory calibration.  To do this, power up the MCU, let its internal temperature stabilize, and then measure the actual clock frequency relative to an externally calibrated source.  Store the calibration data in EEPROM.

- This approach minimizes material cost since no extra parts are needed.
- There is more production cost since each unit must be individually tested.
- While one can achieve excellent results initially, it can become less accurate over time because the oscillator may drift as it ages.  Also the calibration becomes less accurate at temperatures that are different than what was used in the factory.

Answer (score 0):

PIC MCUs like PIC12, 16, has two clocks on board. One is calibrated and second is not. I do not know accuracy you need, check the DS. I built the watch clock, but used external 32 kHz XTAL. Need some programm adjustment, accuracy less one second a day.